# SQL Server CE Max Database Size Ignored

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I've run into a issue where my "Max Database Size" is ignored.

```
Data Source="database.sdf";Default Lock Timeout=30000;Max Buffer Size=2048;Max Database Size=4000;Persist Security Info=False
```

Getting error:

> The database file is larger than the configured maximum database size. This setting takes effect on the first concurrent database connection only. [ Required Max Database Size (in MB; 0 if unknown) = 391 ]

The 391 is not a number I specified and more than the default values while the number I've specified seems to be ignored.

Comment: Have you double checked (debugged) that you are actually using the expected connection string?

Comment: This is what the debugger says about the connection attributes

`[3] = {[Max Database Size, 4000]}`

Comment: And this is the only app on your PC connecting to the database? No connection in VS Tools or similar? - the first connection to the database is "global" and cannot be changed!

Comment: That correct. Nothing else is accessing the database file.

Comment: Hi marc_s, have you found the solution to this problem?  I have the same issue.  In a small program:
string connectionString = @"Data Source=d:\path\to\MainDB.sdf;Max Database Size=4091;AutoShrink Threshold=100;flush interval=1";
And I get "The database file is larger than ....".  The database itself is small, about 10MB.